# cURL 'malformed url'

Tags: php, url, curl

This url

'http://profile.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=user.viewProfile&friendID=39726387'

works perfectly well in a browser but cURL return's error 3 (malformed url).

Any ideas on a work around?

EDIT:

cURL code:

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    if (!$errmsg =='') {die($err.':'.$errmsg);} 
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: That URL appears to work fine when I load it via cURL.  Can you provide your PHP code?

Comment: You should check the url is null or not.

Comment: My problem was, that i passed the wrong variable to curl... It wasn't an URI. Posted this comment, just in case someone else spent 2 hours searching for what's wrong just to find out that rookie mistake. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get the output of the page when running

```
curl http://profile.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=user.viewProfile&friendID=39726387
```

This also works for me:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://profile.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=user.viewProfile&friendID=39726387');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $out;
```

Edit: Just tried your code posted and it works fine for me. Perhaps the string you are passing into `get_web_page()` is wrong?