# Error: malformed PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get an `HTML` from one website through curl request but I'm getting an error

```
Error: malformed
```

I do not know how to get over it and get `HTML` data of website below is my curl code if any body can help me what i am doing wrong in my code

```
    $url="https://ww1.zone-telechargement1.com/films-gratuit/33649-le-crime-de-l-orient-express-frernch-bdrip.html";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0";
    $headers[] = "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL 'malformed url'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126300/curl-malformed-url)

Comment: @LioraHaydont It may be the same error, but how does the answer there help?

Comment: What is the exact error? And why do you think you need `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, since `GET` is the default?

Comment: Your script works fine for me. You must have a typo in the real script, and you didn't copy it here.